# Preemptive CPU scheduler Simulation in turbo c++

Tags: c++, algorithm, borland-c++

I'm new in turbo c++, and I cant understand the blocks of code here and how they work together to perform the preemptive CPU scheduling. this code is working I found this code in some website , what I want to know is the description of each block of codes. please help me to improve my knowledge in turbo c++. Thank you.

```
   #include<stdio.h>
struct sjf
{
       int bt,at,wt,st,pno,tt,cbt;
};

int get(struct sjf arr[],int t,int n)
{
       int imin,min=9999,i;
       for(i=0;i<n;i++)
       {
              if(arr[i].at<=t&&arr[i].st==0)
                     if(min>arr[i].bt)
                     {
                           min=arr[i].bt;
                           imin=i;
                     }
       }
       return imin;
}

void gantt_chart(struct sjf arr[],int p[],int n,int nop)
{
       int i,a[100],s=0;
       float avgtt=0,avgwt=0;
       printf("***************************************\n");
       printf("GANTT CHART\n");
       printf("0");
       for(i=0;i<n-1;i++)
       {
              while(i<n-1&&p[i]==p[i+1])
              {
                     s++;
                     i++;
              }

              s++;
              printf(" -> [P%d] <- %d",arr[p[i]].pno,s);
              arr[p[i]].wt=s-arr[p[i]].at-arr[p[i]].tt;
       }
       for(i=0;i<nop;i++)
       {
              arr[i].tt+=arr[i].wt;
              avgwt+=arr[i].wt;
              avgtt+=arr[i].tt;
       }
       printf("\n***************************************\n");
       printf("Pro\tArTi\tBuTi\tTaTi\tWtTi\n");
       printf("***************************************\n");
       for(i=0;i<nop;i++)
       {
              printf("[P%d]\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\n",arr[i].pno,arr[i].at,arr[i].cbt,arr[i].tt,arr[i].wt);
       }
       printf("***************************************\n");
       avgwt = avgwt/nop;
       avgtt = avgtt/nop;
       printf("Average Waiting Time : %.2f\n",avgwt);
       printf("Average Turnaround Time : %.2f\n",avgtt);
       return;
}

int iscomplite(struct sjf arr[],int n)
{
       int i;
       for(i=0;i<n;i++)
              if(arr[i].st==0)
                     return 0;
       return 1;
}
int main()
{
       int n,i,a,t=0;
       int p[100];
       float avgwt=0,avgtt=0;
       struct sjf arr[100];
       printf("SJF (Shortest Job First) - Preemptive\n");
       printf("Note -\n1. Arrival Time of at least on process should be 0\n2. CPU should never be idle\n");
       printf("Enter Number of Processes\n");
       scanf("%d",&n);
       for(i=0;i<n;i++)
       {
              printf("Enter Arrival Time & Burst Time for Process [P%d]\n",i);
              scanf("%d%d",&arr[i].at,&arr[i].bt);
              arr[i].pno = i;
              arr[i].cbt = arr[i].bt;
              arr[i].st=0;
              arr[i].tt=arr[i].bt;
              arr[i].wt=0;
       }
       i=0;
       while(1)
       {
              if(iscomplite(arr,n))
                     break;
              a=get(arr,t,n);
              p[i]=a;
              arr[a].bt-=1;
              if(arr[a].bt==0)
                     arr[a].st=1;
              t=t+1;
              i++;
       }
       gantt_chart(arr,p,i,n);
       return 0;
}

/*
SJF (Shortest Job First) - Preemptive
Note -
1. Arrival Time of at least on process should be 0
2. CPU should never be idle
Enter Number of Processes
4
Enter Arrival Time & Burst Time for Process [P0]
0 8
Enter Arrival Time & Burst Time for Process [P1]
1 4
Enter Arrival Time & Burst Time for Process [P2]
2 9
Enter Arrival Time & Burst Time for Process [P3]
3 5
***************************************
GANTT CHART
0 -> [P0] <- 1 -> [P1] <- 5 -> [P3] <- 10 -> [P0] <- 17 -> [P2] <- 26
***************************************
Pro     ArTi    BuTi    TaTi    WtTi
***************************************
[P0]    0       8       17      9
[P1]    1       4       4       0
[P2]    2       9       24      15
[P3]    3       5       7       2
***************************************
Average Waiting Time : 6.50
Average Turnaround Time : 13.00

*/
```

Comment: well you want for us to analyze how and what does some foreign uncommented code? Good luck with that... usually is much faster to code things from scratch then analyze someone else code  especially uncommented and without context. If it was just a specific part of code then no problem but whole program ...